# Can I customize the prefix 'v-' in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Can I customize the prefix 'v-' in Vue?

Such as 'abc-':

`<div abc-for="item in list" abc-text="item"></div>`

instead of:

`<div v-for="item in list" v-text="item"></div>`

Comment: It's unlikely. Why would you want to do so?

Comment: Looking at the source code, the answer is "no". The `v-` prefixes are fixed

Comment: I just wanted to confirm it. Because I remember AngularJS can customize the 'ng-'. Maybe set it to be 'data-v-xxx' to match spec.